# How to enable PHP IMAP for php5-fpm / NGINX?

Tags: php, nginx, fpm, php-imap

We have a NGINX server running on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with php5-fpm.

An application *([OEMPRO](http://octeth.com/))* I'm trying to install on it says:

> PHP IMAP extension is disabled. Please enable it.

How can I enable PHP IMAP?

I've checked our `phpinfo` and it seems that IMAP is there in some way, you can see a screen shot of our [phpinfo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xrTN.jpg).

Although, I couldn't find IMAP in the `mods-available/` directory.

```
# ls /etc/php5/mods-available/
curl.ini  gd.ini  json.ini  mcrypt.ini  mysqli.ini  mysql.ini  opcache.ini  pdo.ini  pdo_mysql.ini  readline.ini  ssh2.ini
```

Do I need to enable it in `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`?

---

### UPDATE

I tried installing IMAP but it doesn't resolve the issue.  OEMPRO still says the IMAP is disabled.

```
# sudo apt-get install php5-imap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libassuan0 libgeoip-dev libgpgme11 libtokyocabinet9
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5-imap
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 235 not upgraded.
Need to get 31.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 158 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe php5-imap amd64 5.4.6-0ubuntu5 [31.7 kB]
Fetched 31.7 kB in 0s (0 B/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package php5-imap.
(Reading database ... 60704 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php5-imap_5.4.6-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php5-imap (5.4.6-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up php5-imap (5.4.6-0ubuntu5) ...
# service php5-fpm restart
php5-fpm stop/waiting
php5-fpm start/running, process 2840
# sudo service nginx restart
* Restarting nginx nginx
```

My `phpinfo` remains the same but it I can now see `imap.ini` in `mods-available/`.

```
# ls /etc/php5/mods-available/
curl.ini  gd.ini  imap.ini  json.ini  mcrypt.ini  mysqli.ini  mysql.ini  opcache.ini  pdo.ini  pdo_mysql.ini  readline.ini  ssh2.ini
```

Comment: I don't see IMAP enabled on the screenshot.

Comment: ok, so I probably need to install it then?  How do you install it for php5-fpm?

Comment: the same way you installed everything else : `apt-get install php5-imap`

Comment: @AlexBlex, I tried that but it didn't work, I've updated my question with more details

Comment: @AlexBlex, it's ok.  I also had to run `sudo php5enmod imap`. Now it's working :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried just installing PHP IMAP from scratch, at first it didn't seem to work but then I discovered I also had to run `sudo php5enmod imap`.

Below is the order which you need to run the commands

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imap

sudo php5enmod imap 

service php5-fpm restart

sudo service nginx restart
```